# How to add an array into another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge two arrays in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Let's suppose I have 2 arrays:

```
a = ['a','b','c'];
b = ['d','e','f'];
```

Is there somehow to easy add the `b` into `a` without having to split and perform an `each` for adding the elements?

Something like:

```
a.push(b);
```

And have an final `a` array with the content:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Thank you for the down votes, guys. :/

Comment: @kle - One of the reasons for downvoting is a lack of research.  There is nothing wrong with your actual post. The problem is that with one simple search you wouldn't have had to ask this in the first place. It's nothing personal :)

Comment: I did search but since I'm not a english speaker, I haven't remembered about the term 'merge'. No problem! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tryied the [`concat()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)?

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var kai = ["Robin"];
var children = hege.concat(stale,kai);
```

Will output:

```
Cecilie,Lone,Emil,Tobias,Linus,Robin
```

Comment: Please don't link to W3schools - [this is a much more trustworthy resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: @eva - **now** I can upvote your answer. I recommend you install [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/8367) to prevent such things happening again :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Array.concat:

```
a = a.concat(b); // a == ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```